# Amazon EC2 6 updates are security updates (The following packages have been kept back)

Tags: amazon-ec2, update

I have kind of a strange situation:

I am running an amazon ec2 instance `Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-58-virtual x86_64)`. Every day when I connect to it through ssh I see the following message:

```
6 packages can be updated.
6 updates are security updates.
```

surely I update them `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`. But it appears again on the next connect. There is already a week this happens every day. Upgrade finishes without any errors, but I see the following in the end:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-headers-virtual linux-image-virtual linux-virtual
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

How can I get rid of this and why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was the reason for these messages and why I was not able to get rid of them with `apt-get install && apt-get update`.

The reason why I was not able to install them is after each upgrade they were keeping back (not installed). This is because these are security updates and as far as I got they modify the kernel. So you need to tell the system to do this with.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

For more information about these things [look at](https://askubuntu.com/a/602/202354) the questions I [found it](https://askubuntu.com/a/64316/202354) (beware people say that you have to be careful enough before doing this).

When I updated everything I saw the following message 
**** System restart required *******. I solved it with [this command](https://askubuntu.com/a/258309/202354) `sudo reboot`.